# Likelihood-ratio gradient estimator in linear dynamical system in python (Jax)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, inference, gradient, linear-dynamical-system

**TL;DR**

- I am trying to implement the likelihood-ratio gradient estimator in a linear dynamical system (LDS) with Gaussian transition noise and Gaussian observation noise
- I am currently using python and the Jax library for automatic differentiation.
- The results look like a negated version of what I should be getting
- Could you please look at my code below and tell me what's wrong with it, and how it could be fixed if you have an idea?

Hi,

I am trying to implement the likelihood-ratio gradient estimator and the reparameterized gradient estimator in a simple linear dynamical system (LDS). I want to use those gradient estimators to infer the transition parameter of the LDS.

The system can be defined as follows

$$p(X, Z) = p(x^0, ..., x^T, z^0 ..., z^T) = p(z^0 | \mu_0, V_0) \prod^T_{t=2} p(z^t | z^{t-1}, A, B) \prod^T_{t=1} p(x^t|z^t, C, E)$$

where $x^t$s are noisy observations of $z^t$s, and all distributions are Gaussian:
$$p(z^0 | \mu_0, V_0) = \mathcal{N}(z^0|\mu_0, V_0)$$
$$p(z^t | z^{t-1}, A, B) = \mathcal{N}(z^t|Az^{t-1}, B)$$
$$p(x^t|z^t, C, E) = \mathcal{N}(x^t|Cz^{t}, E)$$

Now I am trying to learn the transition parameter $A$, by maximising the marginal likelihood
$$\mathbb{E}_{p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B)} [p(X | Z, C, E)]$$

Plotting the marginal likelihood objective as a function of A gives the following curve:
[image]

The observations $X$ used to compute the marginal likelihood were generated using a transition parameter $A=1.0$, which can be seen as the maximum is reached for $A=1$ on the plot.

To maximise this objective, I need to compute the gradient of the marginal likelihood. Using the the Likelihood-ratio and Reparameterized gradients, the gradient can be defined as follows:

- **Reparameterized Gradient**:
  $$\nabla_A \mathbb{E}_{p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B)} [p(X | Z, C, E)] = \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_T)} [\nabla_Ap(X | T_{\mu_0, V_0, A, B}(\epsilon), C, E)]$$
  where
  $$T_{\mu_0, V_0, A, B}(\epsilon) = (T_{\mu_0, V_0}(\epsilon_0), T_{A, B}(\epsilon_1), ..., T_{A, B}(\epsilon_T))$$
  where
  $$T_{A, B}(\epsilon_t) = A * z_{t-1} + \sqrt{B} * \epsilon_t$$
  $$T_{A, B}(\epsilon_t) = A * T_{\mu_0, V_0, A, B}(\epsilon_{t-1}) + \sqrt{B} * \epsilon_t$$
- **Likelihood-ratio Gradient:**
  $$\nabla_A \mathbb{E}_{p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B)} [p(X | Z, C, E)] = \mathbb{E}_{p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B)} [\nabla_A \log{(p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B))} * p(X | Z, C, E)]$$

Now I am fairly confident I have implemented the Reparameterized (RP) gradients correctly, as (1) my optimization procedure converges to the correct value of A, and (2) The RP gradient curve seems to match what I would expect the objective function's gradient to look like:

[image]

On the other hand, my Likelihood-ratio (LR) gradients seem to be wrong. While I do converge to the right value of $A$ when using them, they are not equal to the RP gradient values, but rather look like a negated version of the RP gradients. This goes against the theory: both gradient estimator values should be the same (or at least very close, due to the Monte-Carlo estimation imprecision). This problem is very clear when plotting the LR and RP gradients in the same figure as the objective function: they look symmetrical w.r.t the x-axis.

[image]

I have been (unsuccessfully) trying to find the bug in my code for days. I have implemented my gradient estimators in python using the Jax library for automatic differentiation. Below are the three functions I use to compute the likelihood-ratio gradients $\mathbb{E}_{p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B)} [\nabla_A \log{(p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B))} * p(X | Z, C, E)]$:

**Likelihood:** $p(X|Z, C, E)$

```py
def get_likelihood(C, E, zs, xs):
    likelihood = 1
    for i in range(zs.shape[0]):
        likelihood *= jax.scipy.stats.norm.pdf(xs[i], loc= C * zs[i], scale=jnp.sqrt(E))
    return likelihood
```

**Gradient of the log pdf:** $\log{(p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B))}$

```py
def logpdf(mu0, V0, A, B, zs):
        joint_logpdf = jax.scipy.stats.norm.logpdf(zs[0], loc=mu0, scale=jnp.sqrt(V0))
        for i in range(1, zs.shape[0]):
            joint_logpdf += jax.scipy.stats.norm.logpdf(zs[i], loc=A * zs[i - 1], scale=jnp.sqrt(B))
        return joint_logpdf
```

**Likelihood ratio gradient:** $\mathbb{E}_{p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B)} [\nabla_A \log{(p(Z| \mu_0, V_0, A, B))} * p(X | Z, C, E)]$

```py
from jax import grad, vmap

def lr_loss_grad(mu0, V0, A, B, C, E, xs, zs):
    z_grad_func = vmap(grad(logpdf, argnums=2), in_axes=(None, None, None, None, 1))
    z_grads = z_grad_func(mu0, V0, A, B, zs)

    likelihood_func = vmap(get_likelihood, in_axes=(None, None, 1, 1))
    likelihood = likelihood_func(C, E, zs, xs)

    lr_grad = jnp.multiply(z_grads, likelihood)
    return lr_grad.mean()
```

In the code above, `mu0, V0, A, B, C, E` are the distribution parameters mentioned above. `zs` is a 2D array of latent states of shape (number of time steps, number of samples), and `xs` is a 2D array of the noisy observations of `zs`. `xs` also has shape (number of time steps, number of samples).

For those unfamiliar with it, Jax's `vmap` function parallelises operations over specified axes. Here, I am parallelising the computation of the gradient of the `logpdf()` function over all samples, which can be computed independently. Similarly, I parallelise the computation of the `get_likelihood()` function over all samples.

**My question is**: Could anyone please indicate how my implementation of the likelihood-ratio gradient estimator is wrong and how could I fix it? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Nice example for JAX. A suggestion would be to take a R implementation and try to reproduce it, such as [R package for statistical inference in dynamical systems using kernel based gradient matching: KGode](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00180-020-01014-x.pdf).